# Noogie = concussive force?

Tags: brain, brain-damage

Can rubbing ones head vigorously with the knuckles result in brain trauma (essentially a hard scalp massage with the knuckles). Forceful enough that it is putting pressure on the scalp and causing localized pressure and pain. I would assume not, because there is no rotational or linear force causing the neck to swivel, but I'm not sure